# How do I calculate albedo in QGIS from a Landsat 8 image downloaded from EarthExplorer

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, landsat-8, earth-explorer

I'm using QGIS and I'm struggling to calculate the albedo from the images. I don't understand how to use GRASS as every time I use it, I get something that doesn't make sense.

Sor far, I have downloaded the individual band files from EarthExplorer and loaded them into QGIS, next, I use i.albedo on QGIS, and select the 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 bands. After, I click the LandSat 8 box and click run.

The generated layer produced has completely wrong albedo values, and isn't what you would expect from the image, e.g. ice doesn't show as high albedo.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour] to better understand how our Question and Answer model operates. We are not a tutorial site, but instead a *problem-solving* one. Walking anyone through anything is off-charter here. If you [Edit] the Question to tell us exactly what you have and what you have done, and the result, then maybe someone can point out your problem. Just telling us it doesn't make sense isn't enough.